# OpenCL Image reading not working on dynamically allocated array

Tags: opencl

I'm writing an OpenCL program that applies a convolution matrix on an image. Everything works fine if I store all pixel on an array `image[height*width][4]` (line 65,commented) (sorry, I speak Spanish, and I code mostly in Spanish). But, since the images I'm working with are really large, I need to allocate the memory dynamically. I execute the code, and I get a `Segmentation fault` error.

After some poor man's debugging, I found out the problem arises after  executing the kernel and reading the output image back into the host, storing the data into the dynamically allocated array. I just can't access the data of the array without getting the error.

I think the problem is the way the `clEnqueueReadImage` function (line 316) writes the image data into the `image` array. This array was allocated dynamically, so it has no predefined "structure".

But I need a solution, and I can't find it, nor on my own or on Internet.

The C program and the OpenCL kernel are here:
https://gist.github.com/MigAGH/6dd0fddfa09f5aabe7eb0c2934e58cbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use pointers to pointers (unsigned char**). Use a regular pointer instead:

```
unsigned char* image = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*ancho*alto*4);
```

Then in the for loop:

```
for(i=0; i<ancho*alto; i++){
    unsigned char* pixel = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*4);
    fread (pixel, 4, 1, bmp_entrada);
    image[i*4] = pixel[0];
    image[i*4+1] = pixel[1];
    image[i*4+2] = pixel[2];
    image[i*4+3] = pixel[3];
    free(pixel);
}
```